# System.out.println(NOT_AN_EMPTY_STRING); printing out an empty string (a.k.a. nothing)

Tags: java

Okay, let me paraphrase my question:

Code:

`System.out.println("Message is:" + focusOwner + focusOwner.getPage() == null + focusOwner.getText());`

Output:

`false`

Alternative code:

`System.out.println("Message is:" + focusOwner);`

Output:

`Message is:pscript.gui.elements.Answer[,0,98,639x22,invalid,layout=net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@677b15f3,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]`

Some facts:

focusOwner is class Answer which extends Element which extends JPanel. toString() method is never overriden. Proof:

```
public class Answer extends Element
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel letter;
    private JCheckBox check;
    private Question question;

    //getter and setters
    void setQuestion(Question question)
    {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public Question getQuestion()
    {
        return question;
    }

    JLabel getLetter()
    {
        return letter;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect()
    {
        return check.isSelected();
    }

    public String getLetterText()
    {
        return letter.getText();
    }

    //navigational methods
    @Override
    public Element getPreviousElement()
    {
        Element previousElement = getQuestion().getPreviousAnswer((Answer) getElement());

        if (previousElement != null)
        {
            return previousElement; 
        }

        else
        {
            return getQuestion();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Element getNextElement()
    {
        Element nextElement = getQuestion().getNextAnswer((Answer) getElement());

        if (nextElement != null)
        {
            return nextElement;
        }

        else
        {
            nextElement = getPage().getNextElement(getQuestion());

            if (nextElement != null)
            {
                return nextElement;
            }

            else
            {
                Page nextPage = getChapter().getNextPage(getPage());

                if (nextPage != null)
                {
                    return nextPage.getLastElement().lastElement();
                }

                else
                {
                    Chapter nextChapter = getDocument().getNextChapter(getChapter());

                    if (nextChapter != null)
                    {
                        return nextChapter.getTitle();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        return getDocument().getChapter(1).getTitle();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //other methods
    private Element addNextElement()
    {
        if (getQuestion().getAnswerCount() < 5)
        {
            return addNextAnswer();
        }

        else
        {
            return addNextQuestion();
        }   
    }

    private Answer addNextAnswer()
    {
        Answer nextAnswer = new Answer();

        getQuestion().addAnswer(nextAnswer, getQuestion().getAnswerIndex((Answer) getElement())+1);
        getQuestion().rewriteLetters();

        return nextAnswer;
    }

    private Question addNextQuestion()
    {
        Question nextQuestion = new Question();

        getPage().addElement(nextQuestion, getPage().getElementIndex(getQuestion())+1);
        getChapter().rewriteNumbers();

        return nextQuestion;
    }

    private Element removeAnswer()
    {
        Element previousElement = getPreviousElement();

        Question question = getQuestion();

        question.removeAnswer((Answer)getElement());
        question.rewriteLetters();

        return previousElement;
    }

    private void checkLoop()
    {   
        Question question = getQuestion();

        if (question != null)
        {
            getDocument().setSaved(false);

            if ((check.isSelected()) && (question.checkFlag == false))
            {       
                question.checkFlag = true;
                int answerCount = question.getAnswerCount();

                for (int i = 1; i <= answerCount; i++)
                {
                    question.getAnswer(i).check.setSelected(false);
                }

                check.setSelected(true);
                question.checkFlag = false;
            }   
        }
    }

    //actions
    @Override
    void primaryAction()
    {
        addNextElement().takeFocus();
    }

    @Override
    void secondaryAction()
    {
        addNextQuestion().takeFocus();
    }

    @Override
    void deleteAction()
    {
        removeAnswer().takeFocus();
    }

    //constructors
    Answer()
    {
        super();

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        //TODO
        check = new JCheckBox();
        check.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        check.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0)
            {
                checkLoop();
            }
        });

        add(check, "top, gapleft " + LayoutConstants.CHECK_SPACE_LEFT + ", gaptop "+ LayoutConstants.CHECK_ABOVE + ", w " + LayoutConstants.CHECK_WIDTH);

        letter = new JLabel("a)", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        letter.setFont(Main.otherFont);
        letter.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(letter, "top, gaptop " + LayoutConstants.LETTER_ABOVE + ", w " + LayoutConstants.LETTER_WIDTH);

        getTextBox().setMargin(LayoutConstants.ANSWER_INSETS);
        add(getTextBox(), "span, grow, push, w " + LayoutConstants.ANSWERBOX_WIDTH);
    }

    public Answer(String text, boolean correct)
    {
        this();
        getTextBox().setText(text);
        check.setSelected(correct);
    }
}
```

Element:

```
public class Element extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea textBox = new JTextArea();
    private Page page = null;
    private InputMap inputM = getTextBox().getInputMap();
    private ActionMap actionM = getTextBox().getActionMap();

    //getter and setters
    Element getElement()
    {
        return this;
    }

    void setPage(Page page)
    {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public Page getPage()
    {
        return page;
    }

    Chapter getChapter()
    {
        return getPage().getChapter();
    }

    Document getDocument()
    {
        return getChapter().getDocument();
    }

    public JTextArea getTextBox()
    {
        return textBox;
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return getTextBox().getText();
    }

    public void setText(String text)
    {
        getTextBox().setText(text);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return getTextBox().getText().equals("");
    }

    //other methods
    public void takeFocus()
    {
        getDocument().setFocusOwner(getElement());  
        scrollRectToVisible(getTextBox().getBounds());
        getTextBox().grabFocus();
    }

    void addListener()
    {
        AbstractDocument document = (AbstractDocument) getTextBox().getDocument();
        document.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
            {
                getDocument().setSaved(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
            {
                getDocument().setSaved(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
            {
                getDocument().setSaved(false);
            }
        });
    }

    Element lastElement()
    {
        if (getElement() instanceof Question)
        {
            if (((Question) getElement()).getAnswerCount() != 0)
            {
                return ((Question) getElement()).getLastAnswer();
            }
        }

        return getElement();
    }

    //navigational methods
    public Element getPreviousElement()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public Element getNextElement()
    {
        return null;
    }

    //actions
    void primaryAction() {}

    void secondaryAction() {}

    private void tertiaryAction()
    {
        Chapter chapter = getChapter();
        int chapterIndex = getDocument().getChapterIndex(chapter);

        new CreateChapterDialog(getDocument(), chapterIndex+1); //TOD quaternary maybe??

        getDocument().setKeyPressed(false);
    }

    void deleteAction() {}

    private void upAction()
    {
        getPreviousElement().takeFocus();
    }

    private void downAction()
    {
        getNextElement().takeFocus();
    }

    //constructors
    Element()
    {   
        setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0, gap 0!"));

        getTextBox().setLineWrap(true);
        getTextBox().setWrapStyleWord(true);

        getTextBox().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
                getDocument().setKeyPressed(false);
            }
        });

        CustomDocumentFilter filter;

        if (this instanceof Title)
        {
            getTextBox().setFont(Main.titleFont);
            filter = new CustomDocumentFilter(250);
        }

        else if (this instanceof Question)
        {
            getTextBox().setFont(Main.questionFont);
            filter = new CustomDocumentFilter(500);
        }

        else
        {
            getTextBox().setFont(Main.otherFont);
            filter = new CustomDocumentFilter(500);
        }

        AbstractDocument document = (AbstractDocument) getTextBox().getDocument();
        document.setDocumentFilter(filter);

        //primary action
        inputM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "enter");
        actionM.put("enter", new AbstractAction()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                if (!getDocument().isKeyPressed())
                {
                    getDocument().setKeyPressed(true);
                    getDocument().setSaved(false);
                    primaryAction();
                }
            }
        });

        //secondary action
        inputM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift ENTER"), "pressedShiftEnter");
        actionM.put("pressedShiftEnter", new AbstractAction()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (!getDocument().isKeyPressed())
                {
                    getDocument().setKeyPressed(true);
                    getDocument().setSaved(false);
                    secondaryAction();
                }
            }
        });

        //tertiary action
        inputM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control ENTER"), "pressedCtrlEnter");
        actionM.put("pressedCtrlEnter", new AbstractAction()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                if (!getDocument().isKeyPressed())
                {
                    getDocument().setKeyPressed(true);
                    getDocument().setSaved(false);
                    tertiaryAction();
                }
            }
        });

        //up action
        inputM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift TAB"), "shiftTab");
        actionM.put("shiftTab", new AbstractAction()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                upAction();
            }
        });

        //down action
        inputM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"), "Tab");
        actionM.put("Tab", new AbstractAction()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                downAction();
            }
        });

        //delete action
        inputM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift DELETE"), "shiftDelete");
        actionM.put("shiftDelete", new AbstractAction()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                if (!getDocument().isKeyPressed())
                {
                    getDocument().setKeyPressed(true);
                    getDocument().setSaved(false);
                    deleteAction();
                }
            }
        });

        getTextBox().addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
            {
                getDocument().setFocusOwner(getElement());
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

focusOwner.getPage() returns one of it's private variables, which is or isn't null (in this particular case it isn't).

focusOwner.getText() calls getText() method of a JTextArea included in the class and returns it's return value (which really is an empty string in this case).

There. That's the closest thing to the SSCCE I can give you.

**EDIT:**

How do you explain this:

```
System.out.println("Message is:" + focusOwner + focusOwner.getPage() == null + focusOwner.getText());
System.out.println("Message is:" + focusOwner);
```

returning this:

```
false
Message is:pscript.gui.elements.Answer[,0,98,639x22,invalid,layout=net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@1b2a8c70,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

We are talking about value of the SAME variable being printed out in two CONSECUTIVE lines of code and it NOT HAVING THE SAME VALUE.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Come on now.... Where is your [sscce](http://sscce.org)? If you can't create an sscce, then you haven't isolated your problem, ... and neither can we, unless you **force** us to create the SSCCE ourselves, which really isn't fair to us since we're volunteers, is it? Put in some effort or just forget it and delete this question.

Comment: You showed us output for concatenation of strings and Boolean expression and for some object.  Where's is the case with outputting *nothing* (as your title says)?

Comment: Outtputing object is a JPanel extension with it's toString() method untouched and not overriden. It should still behave as a normal JPanel in println() method.

Comment: @Karlovsky120: sorry, but there's no way for us to make heads or tails out of your code because 1) it is massive, and 2) 99% is completely unrelated to your problem. You are probably coming here prematurely before you've done enough debugging to first isolate the problem. I suggest that you do just this, either with a debugger or with println statements, so that you can at least find out where your bug is, because surely you have one. Then if you still don't have a solution, distill your code down into a fully compliant [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: focusOwner.getPage() is working fine. focusOwner.getText() is working fine. "message:" is a String. focusOwner's native toString() method is not tampered with or overriden. Nothing else could be the problem. I don't know how is this even possible.

Comment: You have a bug, your code, not Swing, period, end of story. Now your job is to isolate it. Please delete this question and get to work.

Comment: It's like you write "a"+"b" in one line, and "a"+"b"+"c"+"d" in the other. Return value of the first is "a", and of the second is "abcd":
I know how to look for a bug, but we are talking about core mechanics of Java and it's operators being broken by this: I don't know how to chase THAT down.

Comment: I mean, I know that core Java is fine and that there is no bug there, but how can you explain output of same variable being different in two consecutive lines of code just because I printed something else along with it.

Comment: I can't explain code that I don't understand. I fear that you're over simplifying complex code in your explanations above and are looking at the wrong code for the problem. Please try to find some way to reproduce your problem in the smallest bit of code possible and post it here, or if absolutely necessary in pastebin (which I usually avoid).

Comment: Just look at the edit I wrote. I DO NOT UNDERSTAND THE PROBLEM at all. I can handle variable returning null when it should return something else. But what I don't understand is a variable returning two different values in two consecutive lines of code. And I'm talking about a local varaible, there is no multithreading issue here. I can't find the bug if it seems to be breaking core laws of Java. How do you find a bug which breaks the behaviour of Java source code?

Comment: Glad you've got it solved!

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry if I came across rude anywhere before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the question is why

```
System.out.println("Message is:" + focusOwner + focusOwner.getPage() == null + focusOwner.getText());
```

prints `false` rather than the long string you got in the other case:

The `+` operator has higher precedence than the `==` operator. Thus what you are printing is:

```
("Message is:" + focusOwner + focusOwner.getPage()) == (null + focusOwner.getText())
```

Or the result of an equality comparison between two `String` objects. Obviously the two sides are not equal.

What you want is

```
System.out.println("Message is:" + focusOwner + (focusOwner.getPage() == null) + focusOwner.getText());
```

Comment: Now that's a good pick up!

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I love you.